# How can i extract lines between two specific lines from text file?

Tags: java

I have a big text file and i want to extract data between 2 specific lines, where i know the 1st and last lines :

1st line which is fixed in pattern : "<@@ ------ Notes Process Info -> Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:  43d8] (Time 16:06:56) ------ @@>"

last line which is fixed in pattern : "<@@`enter code here` ------ Notes Process Info -> Load Modules for Process :: [ntaskldr:  3e08] (Time 16:06:59) ------ @@>"

but the number of lines will be as much as the log generated.

TEXT File as follows :

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [Secure System:  0048] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [Registry:  0080] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [    smss:  01d0] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   csrss:  0358] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [ wininit:  03c4] - (5) Access is denied.

<@@ ------ Notes Process Info -> Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:  43d8] (Time 16:06:56) ------ @@>

1.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [services:  017c] - (5) Access is denied.

2.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [Memory Compression:  0c04] - (5) Access is denied.

3.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SecurityHealthService:  1404] - (5) Access is denied.

4.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SgrmBroker:  14f4] - (5) Access is denied.

5.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   csrss:  08d8] - (5) Access is denied.

<@@ ------ Notes Process Info -> Call Stack :: [ NLNOTES:  43d8] (Time 16:06:56) ------ @@>

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [Memory Compression:  0c04] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SecurityHealthService:  1404] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SgrmBroker:  14f4] - (5) Access is denied.

ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   csrss:  08d8] - (5) Access is denied.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    NLNOTES_Reader nl = new NLNOTES_Reader();
    String NLfile = "src/data.txt"; 

        try
        {   
            String[] lines = nl.readLines(NLfile);    

            for (String line : lines) 
            {
                if (line.contains("Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:"))
                     { 
                           System.out.println(line);                                                
                    }

            }
        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            // Print out the exception that occurred
           System.out.println("Unable to create "+NLfile+": "+ie.getMessage());   
           ie.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

1.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [services:  017c] - (5) Access is denied.

2.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [Memory Compression:  0c04] - (5) Access is denied.

3.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SecurityHealthService:  1404] - (5) Access is denied.

4.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [SgrmBroker:  14f4] - (5) Access is denied.

5.ERROR (4): can't attach to process [   csrss:  08d8] - (5) Access is denied.

Comment: So you want to extract everything from after "Notes Process Info -> Call Stack for Process" until the next "Notes Process Info -> Call Stack for Process"?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily doable with streams. You can use the `dropWhile` and `takeWhile` methods.

If you have an array of the lines in a file, you can do something like this.

```
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(lines)
    .dropWhile(line -> !line.equals("first line"))
    .skip(1) // skip the start line
    .takeWhile(line -> !line.equals("last line"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a result, you get a list of all lines between 2 specific lines (not including those specific lines).

In addition, if you can, it's better to use `BufferedReader` to read a file here, because it has a `lines()` method, which returns a stream of lines in the file. This way you won't actually have to store the entire file in memory.

```
List<String> result;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(NLfile))) {
    result = reader.lines()
        .dropWhile(line -> !line.equals("first line"))
        .skip(1) // skip the start line
        .takeWhile(line -> !line.equals("last line"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to create " + NLfile + ": " + ie.getMessage());   
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update**: This solution only applies to Java 9+.

Comment: @Harishkumar can you please provide the full error? It's difficult to say what's wrong without context.

Comment: sharing you a link https://snipboard.io/Hk43xE.jpg if i haven't coded it correctly please guide i am beginner in this...thanks in advance.

Comment: @Harishkumar, as it turns out, `dropWhile` and `takeWhile` were added in Java 9. If you are using Java 8, then you can't use these methods. But if this is just a learning project, I recommend updating to a newer version of Java.

Comment: please click the link https://snipboard.io/gSDHh3.jpg i have tried it with version 9 aw well as 13 i don't know what is happening

Comment: @Harishkumar I've never used Eclipse, but I think that you have to explicitly set the Java language version for the project, because I see some parameters (e.g. `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`) that suggest, that you changed the VM to 13, but the language version is still 8. I may be wrong and these parameters may be related to Eclipse itself, and not to your project, but I think you should look into changing the Java language version for the project.

Answer (score -1):

you say that the end line contains `Notes Process Info -> Load Modules for Process` but I cannot see it in your text file...

Regarding the text file you gave, simply use the following code:

```
        String NLfile = "src/data.txt";
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(NLfile))) {
            String line;
            boolean keepLine = false;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

               //begin keeping lines in the result list
               if (line.contains("Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:")) {
                   keepLine = true;
                   continue;

               //exit while loop, no need to read the other lines
               } else if (line.contains("Call Stack :: [ NLNOTES:")) {
                   break;
               }

               //add the lines in the result list
               if (keepLine) {
                   lines.add(line);
               }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            // Print out the exception that occurred
           System.out.println("Unable to create "+NLfile+": "+ie.getMessage());   
           ie.printStackTrace();
        }
```